# Command Timeout | asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

I have a problem with command timeout when I run this code :

```
string vUser = txtUser.Text.ToString();
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(vUser, radiobtn.SelectedValue);
Membership.DeleteUser(vUser);
```

The problem occur at

```
Membership.DeleteUser(vUser)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add what does the DeleteUser function does? Is there an SQL call there? Because most likely, it is failing there due to SQL Query timeout

Comment: the func from using System.Web.Security;
 so i don't know how to see the SQL call

Comment: Have you written a custom membership provider? What membership provider does your web.config file show you using?